# sklearnにおけるNNでの予測

Tags: python, python3

以下のコードで予測しようとすると、エラーが出てしまいます。
調べてもクリティカルなものが出てこなかったため、教えていただけるとありがたいです。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

**現状のコード:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import codecs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

with codecs.open("17t1906.csv",mode="r",encoding="cp932",errors="ignore") as f:
 train = pd.read_csv(f,delimiter="," , header=3)
with codecs.open("202006.csv",mode="r",encoding="cp932",errors="ignore") as g:
 test = pd.read_csv(g,delimiter="," , header=3)

from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

train = train.dropna()
test = test.dropna()

train_x = train.iloc[:,1:5]
train_y = train.iloc[:,5]

test_x = test.iloc[:,1:5]
test_y = test.iloc[:,5]

clf = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes = 100)
clf.fit(train_x,train_y)
y_pred = clf.predict(test_x)
print(y_pred)
print(mean_squared_error(test_y,y_pred))
print(np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(test_y,y_pred)))
```

Comment: `train.iloc[:,5]` などの部分でエラーになっている可能性があります。この場合、データフレーム `train` の**6列目**のデータを取り出すことになるので、`len(train.columns)`, `len(test.columns)` の値を確認してみてください。

Comment: エラー発生箇所はどこでしょうか？